# Windows 10 Jumplist missing item

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, jumplist

I've yet another problem with Windows 10. My pinned/recent locations shortcuts in `windows explorer` jump-list are not working anymore. The issue was created only a few days ago so I think an automatic update caused it. I just see a message, whenever I click a pinned/recent location in my `windows explorer` jumplist, that states

> The item you selected is unavailable. it might have been moved, renamed, or removed. Do you want to remove it from the list?

Clicking `Delete` doesn't do anything.

I've double checked the items' existence and tried unpinning and re-pinning `windows explorer` to taskbar without any success. Below is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Just received `Windows10 Update: kb3093266` and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: No answers at all? I'm extremely sorry to have installed this non-sense privacy hog called windows 10. It's windows vista all over again. I'm switching back to windows 7 ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some recent windows update seems to have fixed this issue